# Immediate Window for Eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, immediate-window

Does Eclipse have an analog to Visual Studio's "Immediate Window", a window where I can evaluate statements while in the debugger?

Comment: Please accept Todd's answer as the accepted answer, AdamC's is useful but is more analogous to the Watch Window, whereas Todd has found the actual analog to the Immediate window

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Eclipse has a really cool concept call [Scrapbook Pages](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61137.html) where you can evaluate statements even when you're not debugging.  However, if you want to eval code using values from the current program, go to Window->Show View->Expressions.  There you can put in any expression you want and track it as your program executes.

Comment: Expressions are pretty close. Thanks!

Comment: while the answer is correct, in some way, Todds answer is better, as he provied a more exact analogy for VS Immediate Window

Comment: auto-completion doesn't seem to work in the expression window. it's not convenient for evaluating snippets while debugging.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about Scrapbook Pages.

Comment: Expression does not work exactly like immediate window in Visual Studio, Todd's answer is much better and should be taken as answer.

Comment: I think I should downvote this answer in favor of the next one about the Display window

Answer (score 136):

Yes.  The view name is "Display".

Window->Show View->Other
It is under the Debug folder.

Once in there you evaluate statements while in the debugger.

Comment: i would recommend updating this as the correct answer as it is much closer to the immediate window than the "expressions view".

Comment: Thanks for that - I was missing the immediate window!

Comment: Select the statement, right-click and then Execute. You can also press the little play button on the display toolbar.

Comment: another option to open it Ctrl+Num 3 , then type expression

Comment: Do function calls work in the display window? They don't seem to work for me, or maybe I am misunderstanding how they work. If I enter a function name and hit enter, it doesn't display the return value.

Comment: In eclipse 2019-09 R, it is called **Debug Shell**

Answer (score 5):

Inspect ctrl-shift-i or Display ctrl-shift-d?

Comment: To clarify, you can highlight some code within the debugger and hit ctrl+shift+i or right-click->inspect to see the evaluation of the code