# Is there an eclipse equivalent to the Visual Studio "Command Window"?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

I've just gotten really hooked on the Visual Studio Command Window, being able to type a lot of command rather than reaching for the mouse.  Is there an equivalent in eclipse?  Or is there another convenient way to go mouse-less?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112123/immediate-window-for-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a quick, mouse-less way to type and execute commands, check out the Quick Access feature. Just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and start typing the name of a command. 
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100812-dk21k8kfgjx3finmpx1qmnrwj1.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100812-dk21k8kfgjx3finmpx1qmnrwj1.png)

You can execute commands, however, it is lacking the parameters. Eclipse is missing the scripting capabilities. There are some plugins and projects that try to complement that, but nothing standard.

Answer (score 3):

The closest editor in Eclipse would be a **[Scrapbook page](https://www.eclipsezone.com//eclipse/forums/t61137.html)**, where you can execute Java expressions without having to create a new Java program.
This is a neat way to quickly test an existing class or evaluate a code snippet.

But this isn't exactly equivalent to a [Visual Studio Command Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-window?view=vs-2015), and more akin to an [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2015) in Visual Studio.
Still it can be handy.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipsezone.com](http://www.eclipsezone.com/admin/forum/servlet/JiveServlet/download/18111-61137-91979999-3706/inspect.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipsezone.com](http://www.eclipsezone.com/admin/forum/servlet/JiveServlet/download/18111-61137-91979999-3705/run.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Window > Show View > Display

In the Display window, you can type whatever Java code you want, select it and evaluate the result clicking on the "Evaluate" button.

Comment: Only while debugging, and it is running on the target VM.